# jQuery Timeout Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a currently working on a dropdown menu using jQuery. I have run into an issue where the Timeout function is not working at all. The code for it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-sub').hover(
    function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    },
    function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
    },
    function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.has-sub').addClass("tap");
      }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass("tap");
      clearTimeout();
    }
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I trying to do is to create a hover delay for parent of the Dropdown. You would need to hover over the parent for 2 seconds for the Dropdown menu to appear. I also want to pair that with a Slidedown and Slideup effect.

The Slidedown and Slideup functions correctly but the Timeout does not work.

Comment: Once again, reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) is always useful ...

Comment: that means that you are using jQuery hover the wrong way.. and setTimeout belongs to JS....

Comment: jQuery's `.hover()` method only takes 1 or 2 functions as parameters. You're giving it 4. https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: can you provide an HTML too?

Comment: @ymz `setTimeout()` is not a part of JavaScript. It's a method of a host environment object (`window`), but not part of the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: Hi Scott....'setTimeout' is a native part when using javascript... the title is actually **jQuery Timeout**..  I simply assume that I rather be wrong to treat it as JS  feature then a jQuery feature

Comment: @ymz It's not a JavaScript or a JQuery feature. As I said, it is a property of the `window` object, which is provided by the browser, not the language. It is not "native" to JavaScript. You will not find anything about `setTimeout()` in the ECMAScript specification. https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/

Comment: @ymz Also, you are using JavaScript, when you use JQuery. JQuery is nothing more that JavaScript that someone else wrote to provide simpler ways of coding difficult things. It can really be described as a wrapper object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just call **[`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/cleartimeout)** (which is not part of JQuery, by the way), you must provide it with an identifier for the timer you want to cancel.

Also, `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` are not part of JQuery or JavaScript for that matter. They are methods of the `window` object, which is supplied by the browser. They are not part of the language (JavaScript) or the library (JQuery).

Additionally, the **[JQuery .hover() method](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** takes 2 arguments and you are providing 4. I have combined them below, but not knowing exactly what you are trying to do, you may need to adjust that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // This will represent the unique ID of the timer
  // It must be declared in a scope that is accessible
  // to any code that will use it
  
  var timerID = null; 
  
  $('.has-sub').hover(
    function() {
      
      // Clear any previously running timers, so
      // we dont' wind up with multiples. If there aren't
      // any, this code will do noting.
      clearTimeout(timerID);
      
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
      // Set the ID variable to the integer ID returned
      // by setTimeout()
      timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.has-sub').addClass("tap");
      }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
      $(this).removeClass("tap");
      // Clear the particular timer based on its ID
      clearTimeout(timerID);
    }
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: see the @blex comment

Comment: @gaetanoM Updated to address that.

Comment: "but not knowing exactly what you are trying to do"  this is the problem..